# How and why did Naruto's parents rise from the dead in a war?

Tags: naruto

If Naruto's parents (Minato and Kushina) were killed when Kurama attacked the Leaf Village when he was born, how and why did his parents rise from the dead (alive again) in the war with different generations of Hokages?

Answer (score 0):

Minato was resurrected with the edo-tensei by orochimaru.
His mother never appeared during the war arc. He only saw her in his mind when he went to tame the nine tails.